# fread: file not found

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to open a 2.2G file using `fread` from the `data.table` package, but keeping getting the same error (it works for other files, which are less 1G tough):

```
library(data.table)
data.table 1.9.4  For help type: ?data.table
*** NB: by=.EACHI is now explicit. See README to restore previous behaviour.

train  = data.table::fread('train.csv')
```

`Error in data.table::fread("train.csv") : 
 file not found: train.csv`

Of course, the file is present (`read.csv()` works, but is really slow).
I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, on a i686. Appreciate any help!

**NOTE**: The file i'm, trying to read is 'train.gz', which can be found at:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/tradeshift-text-classification/data.

It's a 2.2G csv file, pretty standard.

EDIT: When i use `verbose=TRUE`, it says:

`Input contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open`

Comment: You're sure you have the correct working directory set up and that `list.files(pattern="train.csv")` returns the file information?

Comment: That's for sure, `read.csv` works, thought it's very slow. Also, `fread` works on other files on the same directory.

Comment: Which version of data.table are you using? I am not getting the same error for files that don't exist.

Comment: Version 1.9.4, see edit for details. thanks!

Comment: If the file did not exist, it should give an error like `Error in fread("train.csv") : File is empty: /dev/shm/file1231231391`. So it seems something more involved than that... did you try it on any other large files? Maybe it fails due to the size but just throws a misleading error?

Comment: Or to install the development version and try again?  devtools::install_github("Rdatatable/data.table",  build_vignettes = FALSE)

Comment: @konvas Yes, it works on a 1G file.

Comment: @KFB Version 1.9.5 gives the same error.

Comment: Perhaps your values are not quoted and you need to specify `sep=","`?

Comment: @BondedDust No, i tried everything regarding the parameters.

Comment: Just downloaded and loaded the file using `fread(train)`. `dim(DT)` is 1700000 by 146. It works fine for me.

Comment: It seems that the problem is my Ubuntu 32 bit OS. It works fine on my Mac for example.

Comment: @Fernando, then you should file an issue (with the exact details - what commands you tried, your OS + version, R version etc..) on the github project page.

Comment: Yes, i'll to that. thanks

Comment: Was there any other output when `verbose=TRUE`? Or just that one line.  It is a filename to open and there is no \n, so that's correct behaviour.  Have you tried passing a full path to the file as a way to reveal the problem?

Comment: If you can please copy and paste the full output starting from a bash prompt, showing `pwd` and showing the full output of the R session without anything snipped, that should also help I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well just to close the topic: i upgrade my Ubuntu to x86-64, now `fread` works fine.

Just a summary to help the developers:

1-Downloaded a huge file (2.2G in this case)

2-Try to read with `fread`, and gets the error: `file not found: train.csv`

I was using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x86 and R last stable version.

As pointed out smaller files worked in this scenario (~731 MB).
Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: The same here in Mageia Linux 5 32-bit (R 3.2.3, data.table 1.9.6). The file is a 2.5G CSV, and the symptoms are exactly the same. Will try a 64-bit version tomorrow and report the results.

Answer (score 3):

To open large files on a 32-bit Linux systems, one needs to supply an `O_LARGEFILE` option to the `open` function, which `fread` doesn't do. It's an `open` call that actually fails, but it's erroneously reported as a "file not found" error.

Another way to enable large file support is to pass a `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` option to the compiler while installing the package. Unload and remove `data.table`, put the following into `~/.R/Makevars`:

```
CFLAGS=-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
```

and then issue `R CMD INSTALL /path/to/data.table_X.Y.Z.tar.gz`. The newly installed package will successfully open large files on a 32-bit system.